# mailgun python html templates not working

Tags: python, html, email, mailgun

I'm trying to send html emails with mailgun and python. For testing purposes I downloaded the mailgun template emails from http://blog.mailgun.com/transactional-html-email-templates/, but when I send the inlined version there is a huge gap at the start of the email in both my mobile browser and in apple mail on my desktop.

```
import requests
 ix_html = open("billing.html", "r")
 def send_simple_message():
     return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/_______.mailgun.org/messages",
    auth=("api", "______"),
    data={"from": "Mailgun Sandbox <____>",
          "to": "____",
          "subject": "Hello",
          "html": ix_html})

send_simple_message()
```

I think the problem might be how I am reading the html. I'd like to get this working first with the verified working templates before I proceed with making my own. 
Thanks

Comment: I have kind of the same issue. Have you figured out a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what framework you are using but in Pyramid, you would have something along this lines.

```
from pyramid.renderers import render
import requests

ix_html = render("billing.html", {"l_name": lname, "f_name": fname})
def send_simple_message():
     return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/_______.mailgun.org/messages",
    auth=("api", "______"),
    data={"from": "Mailgun Sandbox <____>",
          "to": "____",
          "subject": "Hello",
          "html": ix_html})

send_simple_message()
```

The [`render`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/renderers.html#pyramid.renderers.render) method needs atleast 2 parameters i.e. template and context information `render(template, context, request=None)`